# Are the HTTP methods different in 1.1 and 1.0?

Tags: http, https

Greetings all,

I've been told by co-workers that the `GET` method is different in HTTP 1.0 and 1.1.

The way it was explained to me was that in HTTP 1.0 `GET` does not have a body, ergo you cannot add additional information in the body. All of the variables have to be specified in the URI as CGI type variables.

However, in HTTP 1.0 `GET` allows a body, so one could specify variables using XML (or whatever) in the body of the `GET` message.

Is this true? I've crawled the web looking for HTTP 1.0/1.1 documents, comparisons and otherwise, but I've never found the above statements? If it is true, can you point me to a reference so I can study up on it?

What about the other methods: `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE`? Are the same or different between 1.0 and 1.1?

Comment: I don't think HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 change w.r.t. `GET` being allowed or disallowed a body in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any method definitions changed.

Technically, you *could* have a request body for GET, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea, or that it'll work with all libraries/intermediaries/servers.

Comment: I'm starting to think its not related to the version of HTTP.I took `HTTP` out of my google searches and started finding hits on HTML that explained that GETs encode the variables in the URI while PUT/POST have the variables in the body.

Comment: John, that's an aspect of HTML forms, not of HTTP itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at the HTTP RFCs?  They're not all that hard to read, and they're the authority.  You could even just look at the 1.1 RFC and see what changed.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: I've already done that. The specs don't answer this question directly. For example, the section on message bodies says that they must not be included if the specification of the requested method does not allow sending an entire-body in requests. Then the section it references does not give that information.

Comment: The closest I found was section 15.1.3 "Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's" which indicates "Authors of services which use the HTTP protocol SHOULD NOT use GET based forms for the submission of sensitive data, because this will cause this data to be encoded in the Request-URI." However, this is the only section that seems to indicate that a GET encodes its data in the URI. And yet, co-workers have since shown me APIs that use GET with parameters in the body.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the suggestion and links to the RFCs.

Comment: The protocol doesn't prevent you from adding in a body (either HTTP 1.0 or 1.1). The real question is why? The semantics of GET are generally dead simple. 

If you're just looking at a comparison of 1.1 and 1.0, there are a few differences (like 1.0 not supporting chunked encoding), but unless you're going to support a very specific 1.0 client, why does it matter?